# How to mock a class with type parameters using Scalamock?

Tags: scala, scalamock

I'm trying to mock this Scala class using Scalamock `v4.4.0`:

```scala
import com.twitter.util.closable

class SimpleKafkaProducer[K, V](val kafkaProducer: KafkaProducer[K, V], val topic: String) extends Closable {...}
```

In my test I have:

```scala
val userCreatedEventPublisher: SimpleKafkaProducer[Long, UserEvent] = mock[SimpleKafkaProducer[Long, UserEvent]]
```

And the error I get at compile time is the following:

```
[error]  found   : org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer[K,V]
[error]  required: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer[Long, event.UserEvent]
[error]     val userCreatedEventPublisher = mock[SimpleKafkaProducer[Long, UserEvent]]
```

Comment: Can you try again with ScalaMock 5.1.0 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, same error with ScalaMock 5.1.0 @Thilo

Comment: Can you show more code? Are you sure you did not define `K` and `V` as something else? Can you try `mock[SimpleKafkaProducer[K,V]]` instead?